# Strange XML structure generated by JAXB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

Why do I get this structure? I would have expected quiz-->questions--> and two question elements, not two questions elements?

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Quiz {

    private List<Question> questions;

    public Quiz() {
        questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        for (Question question : questions) {
            addQuestion(question);
        }
    }

    public void addQuestion(final Question question) {
        if (!(questions.contains(question))) {
            questions.add(question);
        }
    }

    public void removeQuestion(final Question question) {
        if (questions.contains(question)) {
            questions.remove(question);
        }
    }

    public int numberOfQuestions() {
        return questions.size();
    }
}
```

Question:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Question extends AbstractModel {

}

<quiz><questions></questions><questions></questions></quiz>
```

Comment: Please provide the Question class as well.

Comment: Ok, added. I just show the class definition since I don't think the other matters?

Comment: I suspect your collection is not annotated well.

Comment: @zaske Which collection? The one in the quiz?

Comment: Yes, see my answer please. You might need both to use XmlElementWrapper and XmlRefElement.

Answer (score 3):

By default JAXB (JSR-222) implementations do not provide a grouping element.  You can use `@XmlElementWrapper` to get one.

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name="question")
public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Hi, ok. I am still having issues with the other question about the answers doesn't show up. It works when I build the object graph in the same method. Should lists in one object automatically be mapped? Or am I missing an annotation. One-to-one relationship work, but not one-to-many, many-to-many

Comment: @Andy - Where do the answers fit in your model?

Comment: @Andy - please provide the complete class diagram (also of the Answers section).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your collection (i.e - "getQuestions") is not annotated well. 
You should consider using XmlRefElement if you intend to have a list of Question objects or of objects that extend Question (for example, 
in case you have StudentQuestion and LecturerQuestion extend Question and you want objects of these to be added to the collection) 
If you want to put a "wrapper" of a "Questions" over "Question" i.e - have XML that looks like:

```
<Questions>
   <Question></Question>
   <Question></Questions>
</Question>
```

You should annotate the collection with `@XmlElementWrapper(name="Questions")`

Comment: +1 - `@XmlElementRef` is useful if you want the element name based on `@XmlRootElement` of the referenced class.  Otherwise you could use `@XmlElement` as shown in my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13430834/383861